# python-configparser not found on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-3.10, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to install this https://github.com/pimoroni/displayhatmini-python on a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 22.04 and when I run the install.sh it fails on this:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-configparser
```

Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with python. I'm trying to install it using this:

```
apt install python-configparser
```

but I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-configparser
```

`python3 -V` gives me `Python 3.10.12`

So I also tried `apt-get install -y python3-configparser` but that also comes up as not found.

Would I need to uninstall python3 and install python instead? Not sure how to resolve.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Thanks to the comment below, I have installed this but the error persists:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-configparser
./install.sh: line 145: python: command not found
Error parsing configuration...
```

This is the code it refers to:

```
apt_pkg_install python-configparser

CONFIG_VARS=`python - <<EOF
from configparser import ConfigParser
c = ConfigParser()
c.read('library/setup.cfg')
p = dict(c['pimoroni'])
# Convert multi-line config entries into bash arrays
for k in p.keys():
    fmt = '"{}"'
    if '\n' in p[k]:
        p[k] = "'\n\t'".join(p[k].split('\n')[1:])
        fmt = "('{}')"
    p[k] = fmt.format(p[k])
print("""
LIBRARY_NAME="{name}"
LIBRARY_VERSION="{version}"
""".format(**c['metadata']))
print("""
PY3_DEPS={py3deps}
PY2_DEPS={py2deps}
SETUP_CMDS={commands}
CONFIG_TXT={configtxt}
""".format(**p))
EOF`
```

Comment: sudo pip3 install  configparserc  Released: Sep 20, 2023

Comment: @toyotaSupra many thanks! I installed that (with no errors) but my initial error persists. I have posted above the code, I suspect because the install.sh is specifically asking for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3, the `configparser` module is part of the standard libraries (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), so it does not need to be a dependency.

The Ubuntu `python-configparser` package is actually a backport of the Python 3 `configparser` module for Python 2.7.  Since Python 2.7 is deprecated in Ubuntu 22.04, they have (apparently) dropped that package.

But looking at the project you are actually trying to install, it looks like you can modify the `install.sh` script to comment out the `apt_pkg_install python-configparser` ... and the section of the script that installs for Python 2.

I see that someone (you?) has just created an issue tracker for this: https://github.com/pimoroni/displayhatmini-python/issues/17